# how do I extract a value from a JSON object Array of Arrays

Tags: php, html, json

I am having a hard time extracting a value from the following JSON object

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (11) { ["Group"]=> string(2) "18" ["GroupName"]=> string(8) "Wireline" ["Region"]=> string(2) "15" ["RegionName"]=> string(8) "Atlantic" ["Province"]=> string(1) "1" ["ProvinceName"]=> string(13) "New Brunswick" ["City"]=> string(2) "11" ["CityName"]=> string(10) "Campbelton" ["Site"]=> string(2) "37" ["SiteName"]=> string(16) "Campbellton PNCT" ["Year"]=> string(4) "2016" } 
           [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["PlatformID"]=> string(1) "1" ["PlatformTag"]=> string(6) "Access" ["Rack"]=> string(24) "23" Width 36" Depth Rack" ["RackValue"]=> string(1) "2" ["Comments"]=> string(0) "" } 
           [2]=> object(stdClass)#3 (12) { ["Rack"]=> string(31) "23" Width 36" Depth Rack Access" ["RackValue"]=> string(1) "2" ["RackComments"]=> string(0) "" ["Manufacturer"]=> string(6) "werwer" ["Name"]=> string(6) "werwer" ["Quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["RackUnits"]=> string(1) "1" ["Power"]=> string(1) "1" ["ActivePassive"]=> string(6) "Active" ["ACDC"]=> string(2) "AC" ["ConnectivityIDs"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["Connectivity"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Fiber" } } }
```

I am trying to extract each item in a foreach loop within PHP Above is the var_dump of the $data[0] JSON object it demonstrates what the Array item looks like.

My foreach is the following

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["submitdata"]);
      $Forecasts = $data[0];    
foreach($Forecasts as $Forecast){
    echo($Forecast->PlatformID);}
```

but it returns nothing as a result.  Can someone explain to me how to get this from the second Array in the object?

Comment: please use code formating

Comment: Where is $Forecasts defined? Can you paste the code for its definition here?

Comment: Added above so you can see where it has been defined.

Comment: $Forecasts is holding an object not a Array.  Also, index 0 does not have a PlatformID property.  This is only found at index 1.  You could do  $Forecasts = $data[1];   echo($Forecast->PlatformID);  $data is an array so you could loop over that.  I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: the above array example is from the var_dump($data[0]);  there is no element at index 1  the above is one element consisting of 3 inner elements

Comment: @Netherrack it's because your `$data` contain 3 elements and you picked first one and binded it to `$Forecasts` so your `$Forecasts` is not an array but your first object in array

Comment: echo(var_dump($data[1]));  Returns NULL This means there is no items at that index.  its an Array of Arrays  item 1 (1,2,3) item 2 (1,2,3) and so on.  There is nothing at index 1 it only has 1 item in the first place.

Comment: You should write in your question that this array is a `var_dump` of `$data[0]`, so did you have any error? Because you are trying iterate over objects, and only one object got property PlatformId. Another option is to not use object instead of arrays, just use `json_decode($data, true)` and your json will be mapped to an array

Comment: try `$data = json_decode($_POST["submitdata"], true);` - that will make it an array

Answer (score 0):

simply place the Index of the inner array along with the object as shown below.  This will check for the sub item for the PlatformID and return it to the screen.

```
foreach($Forecasts as $Forecast){
    echo($Forecast[1]->PlatformID);}
```